# How to transform a table field type string to a FK type int using SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table called ORGANISATIONS in my db with the following fields : id, name, adress. I also hâve à table called USERS with three fields: userName, companyName, age. Based on this file I would to make a SQL query to create a new table called USERS2. The thing is I would that table to have a field companyID instead of companyName and that field should be a Foreign key on the field Id of the ORGANISATIONS table. Can this be done in one SQL query?

Comment: You mean one statement to read the CSV file, link to the existing table, create the new table and populate it?  Probably not.

Comment: No. I edited my question assuming I hâve 2 tables. Is that possible?

Comment: Probably not - 1. Load CSV file as-is to a temp table 2. run query to populate new table from temp table joined to ORGANISATIONS, 3. delete temp table.  Can be one _script_, but probably not one _statement_

Comment: What is your RDBMS? And let me get this straight, you have two tables Organisations and Users and want to populate a third table USER2. Why not join the two tables - INSERT INTO USERS2 SELECT UserName, Age, Organisation.Id as CompanyID FROM USERS INNER JOIN Organsations ON Users.CompanyName = Organisations.Name You would need to double check to make sure there are not multiple organisations with the same name in which case you would get duplicates for User.